# Remove Quote in Regex Matching

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

The issue now is that I have to extract the `1.0.0.0` out. Here's the regular expression that I can come out with:

```
 var  pattern = "[^\\/]+\\[[a-z]+:\\s" + "AssemblyVersion"+ "(?:Attribute)?\\((.+)\\)\\]" ;
 var theString ="[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]";
 var reAssemblyVersion = new RegExp(pattern,"m");
 reAssemblyVersion.exec(theString);
 var theAnswer = RegExp.$1;       // theAnswer is "1.0.0.0", but I want it to be 1.0.0.0
```

There must be something I did wrong in setting up the `pattern` variable, but couldn't find out.. any ideas?

Comment: You forgot to include quotes in a regex (after "(" and before ")")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your RegEx did not eliminate the double qoutes.

Here is the right one:

```
var  pattern = "[^\\/]+\\[[a-z]+:\\s" + "AssemblyVersion"+ "(?:Attribute)?\\(\\\"(.+)\\\"\\)\\]" ;
//  Here --------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^    ^^^^
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just have something simple as this:

```
\(\"([0-9.]*)\"\)
```